# Magento 2 Hardware Requirement confusion and Upgrading on Live server confusion

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, composer, server-setup, setup-upgrade

I have worked with `Magento1` and `Magento2` both.
But All of my `Magento2` projects are hosted under dedicated server and the permission of `Upgrading` and `Building` using `composer` is given by the client. So there is no problem at all.

But right now i am working with a Magento2 project in which client has given me a `VPS server`. He will give the `Upgrade and Build` permissions but i have some questions of my own.

1. What is the correct Hardware Requirement for Magento2 in terms of RAM, HDD, Cores etc.
2. The most important question "Is is possible to build and setup-upgrade magento2 in local environment and upload the files to live server" like we use to do in Magento1. OR do e have to "setup-upgrade and Build" on the liver server compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

Our old deployment used git to push onto the server. There we used to run a whole load of magento console commands before switching the directories (including `setup:upgrade`). Contrary to normal use, we did all composer updates locally and pushed them after testing.

The hardware depends on the number of products and visitors. 2GB RAM/2 vCPUs should suffice for a basic store, but double that would be more accommodating.